# Почему IDE от JetBrains не видит ни Chrome, ни NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, google-chrome, pycharm, archlinux

Решил изучить React, в качестве ide использую IntelliJ IDEA. Проблема началась даже при попытке запустить простой .html файл в браузере из IDEA:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке запустить его возникает ошибка:
Cannot run program "/usr/bin/google-chrome": error=2, Нет такого файла или каталога
Пытаюсь вручную добавить исполняемый файл Chrome в список, а его просто не видно в каталоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При чём он действительно есть в этой директории:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
google-chrome - это ссылка на google-chrome-stable, я её сделал в надежде, что хотя бы её можно добавить
google-chrome-stable - это непосредственно хромбраузер, при попытке его запустить прямо из файлового менеджера или из консоли - он прекрасно запускается, но idea не видит ни его, ни ссылку на него.
Я совсем недавно пользуюсь linux (у меня KDE Manjaro), возможно не понимаю чего то.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
P.S. Node так же не добавляется
P.P.S В Pycharm тоже не удаётся добавить браузеры